# Which object in jsp page correspond to Model in controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am debugging a Spring MVC web-app using jsp as front-end page. Its controller is populating data into Model :

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setUpForm(HttpServletRequest req, @ModelAttribute UserCommand userCommand,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    userCommand = (UserCommand)session.getAttribute("USER_COMMAND");

    /*
        populate data into fields of userCommand object
        ....
    */

    model.addAttribute("userCommand", userCommand);
    return "nextPage";
}
```

In jsp, I know there are a few implicit object: request, session, pageContext, ...
If I want to view the content of request object, I can set breakpoint in jsp and inspect its content.

The question is: which jsp object does the `Model` object correspond to? My concern is that I want to inspect the content of model object passed from controller to jsp page in scriptlet(<%...%>).

(I use scriptlet because it allows me to set breakpoint. I know there are Expression Language such as ${} but could not use breakpoint and inspect.)

Comment: The path parameter in the form fields describes the names of attributes present in the ModelAttribute.

Comment: model.addAttribute("userCommand", userCommand); will create a request scoped attribute with the key "userCommand". The same object is of course already in the session with the key "USER_COMMAND"